# 2011 Community Moderator Election #2

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election, moderators

*With the growth of the Gaming Stack Exchange, and the loss of Grace Note as a moderator, it is time once again to hold Community Moderator Elections for 2 new moderators. The winners of this election will be joining our remaining group of moderators.*

The second 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Are you... *alive?*

Answer (score 10):

```
OpenSTV version 1.6.1 (http://www.OpenSTV.org/)

Ballot file contains 9 candidates and 157 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 157 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Gaming Moderator Election 2011 using Meek STV.
9 candidates running for 2 seats.

 R|Raven Dream|Mana       |Kevin Y    |bwarner    |Ivo Flipse |FallenAngel
  |er         |           |           |           |           |Eyes       
  |-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
  |sjohnston  |Anna Lear  |Arda Xi    |Exhausted  |Surplus    |Threshold  
  |           |           |           |           |           |           
==========================================================================
 1|    43.0000|    31.0000|     3.0000|     2.0000|    24.0000|    15.0000
  |     7.0000|    15.0000|    17.0000|     0.0000|     0.0000|    52.3334
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices.
==========================================================================
 2|    48.0000|    32.0000|           |           |    25.0000|    16.0000
  |           |    16.0000|    19.0000|     1.0000|     0.0000|    52.0001
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Kevin Y, bwarner, and sjohnston and
  | transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
==========================================================================
 3|    51.0000|    40.0000|           |           |    27.0000|           
  |           |    18.0000|    19.0000|     2.0000|     0.0000|    51.6667
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating FallenAngelEyes and transferring votes. All
  | losing candidates are eliminated. Candidates FallenAngelEyes and Anna
  | Lear were tied when choosing candidates to eliminate. Candidate
  | FallenAngelEyes was chosen by breaking the tie randomly.
==========================================================================
 4|    57.0000|    42.0000|           |           |    29.0000|           
  |           |           |    22.0000|     7.0000|     6.9999|    50.0001
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Anna Lear and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated. Candidate Raven Dreamer has reached the
  | threshold and is elected.
==========================================================================
 5|    64.0000|    52.0000|           |           |    33.0000|           
  |           |           |           |     8.0000|    16.6666|    49.6667
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Arda Xi and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated. Candidate Mana has reached the threshold
  | and is elected.
```

> ## Winners are Raven Dreamer and Mana ಠдಠ.

[image]

The careful reader will notice that at step 3, a random decision was necessary to break a tie (Anna and Fallen both have 16 votes at step 2). Those running the ballot using a graphical tool will be asked to pick one between FallenAngelEyes or Anna Lear, or press Cancel to let the fate choose. The final outcome of the election does *not* change regardless of the choice, however, and running the elections with any number of seats different from 2 will not cause this corner case to happen.

Comment: congrats to both