# When did SE invent Skynet?

Tags: support, community

First, [it started posting](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/2011-community-moderator-election-2).  [Now it's protecting stuff](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24478/can-i-transfer-my-terraria-character-from-one-pc-to-another)?!?  Doesn't sound like your ordinary "[background process](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)" to me...

The only other explanation is that it's a person, but in that case, it would probably be a mod or dev, and they (should) have accounts everywhere.  In that case, why isn't this person using their own account?

Editing by Community♦  indicates anonymous editing, and approvals by Community♦ are made [with a workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86604/why-are-my-suggested-edits-here-approved-by-community/86630#86630) that doesn't apply to posting or protecting.

What's going on here?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it - until it starts *terminating* users... :)

Comment: This by far goes into my box of Top Ten Most Interesting Questions on Gaming SE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Auto-protection was enabled as [part of an old Meta feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers). Specifically, it targets exactly the stuff that we use to judge manual protection - **track records of actual issue**. Or, in simpler terms, Community protects when 3 or more new answers from new users are deleted on a question.

So I guess that puts the answer to your question at May 5th.

Answer (score 5):

What you can't see about that protected question is the three deleted "answers" by 1-rep users that myself and the other mods have converted to comments.

I'm going to make a logical guess that there's a 3 "new user answer deleted" threshold, which that question reached, which triggered the auto-protection.